# Angular directive as angular-translate value

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-interpolate, angular-i18n

i'm having an issue trying to get a directive work as a value of a translation. here's what i have

```
scope.value = '<img class="picture portrait" ng-src="' + url + '"></img>';
scope.key = 'PICTURE';
```

and in my view:

```
<span translate="{{key}}" translate-values="{{value}}" translate-compile></span>
```

when i inspect the element, the ng-src attribute is not on the tag anymore

i configured it with:

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
$translateProvider.usePostCompiling(true);
```

i'm not sure what's going on, but i think the `$sanitize` service strips the ng-src from the html, i don't know how to prevent it, if you have any ideas, they will be warmly welcome